# Adding a ± 10 % line in scatter plot in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, scatter-plot

Im comparing two variables in excel scatter plot  for example measured vs calculated values of velocity and was wondering how would be possible to add ± 10 % line? Just to show how points are deviating.

Comment: Hello Zed, Could you share with us examples of what you already tried ?

What do you mean by 10% line ?

Comment: " to add ± 10 % line" > create another 2 column, by multiplying the Y value by 0.9 & 1.1 , then plot on the same chart.